# how to use hostname like '127.0.0.2:1337' in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using sql server for codeigniter and using the hostname '127.0.0.2:1337' . I am getting the following error like "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings". Please help me how to connect.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.2:1337';
$db['default']['username'] = 'samp';
$db['default']['password'] = 'rms123';
$db['default']['database'] = 'rab';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: No sure, the 127.0.0.2 is localhost.

Comment: default port of SQL server is 1433

Answer (score 3):

`hostname` is just that: host **NAME**. You can't put a port number in there. There's `$db['default']['port']`:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.2';
$db['default']['port'] = 1337;
```

Comment: Yes, i already tried your code $db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.2';
$db['default']['port'] = 1337;but showing the same error like "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings"

Comment: Then your IP/port are incorrect. 127.0.0.2 is a highly unusual IP to be using.

Comment: I am using this "http://127.0.0.2:1337/" host for xampp. It is working fine for my PHP projects, but in Coneigniter only issues. So how i can solve it?